# Eclipse Paho MqttClient object pool

Tags: mqtt, paho

We have a rest service endpoint (Spring MVC) that publishes messages to a mqtt broker. 
We are planning to cache the MqttClient so that we do not have to create it for every request.

What is the best option? Store the MqttClient in each ThreadLocal object?
Use an object pool such as Apache Commons Pool?

Any advice on this would be appreciated. Also if there is already a pool implementation of Paho MqttClient available?

Answer (score 0):

Paho mqtt client is a statefull client. In other words, when it connects to the broker, the TCP connection is live until some of the sides decides to disconnect or there is some ugly error within the network.

Creation of a new mqtt client for every thread (rest client) is not a good idea, IMO.

You are using Spring, maybe you can create the `@Bean` object (singleton bean) with a single method `send()`. There you can create as many clients as you want. Probably one client is ok, but I don't know what is expected load. Then, from you `@Controller` you can execute the `send()` method...

Also, be careful about synchronisation. Every http request is part of a "new" thread, and you have only one mqtt bean.

Comment: I know that the MqttClient is stateful and hence feel that object pooling is a better option. Wanted to know if anyone has done object pooling of MqttClient objects and any gotchas?